# Set transparent background color div over black parent border

Tags: html, css, border, background-color, rgba

I am trying to create some kind of selector menu which has active and nonactive elements and depending on which one is selected it shows one thing or another.

I have set a border for the menu and for the content but I would like to make it "connected" by removing the bottom-border when you select a different menu option. It looked fine since I decided to set a transparent background color to this: rgba(150,150,150,0.5). The border from parent is visible because the background of the selected menu child is not solid.

Simplified html:

```
<div class="menu-alias fac">
  <div id="menu_fac_1" class="alias afac aliselected">
    <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="facalias(1);" class="alias-fac-a">D</a>
  </div>
  <div id="menu_fac_0" class="alias afac ali-nuevo">
    <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="facalias(0);" class="alias-fac-a">+</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="facturacion" id="fac_1" style="display: block;">
  <label for="acc_f_nombre_1" class="acc-label required">
  Nombre:<span class="required">*</span><input id="acc_f_nombre_1" value="D" type="text" class="acc-text upp">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="facturacion" id="fac_0" style="display: none;">
  <label for="acc_f_nombre_0" class="acc-label required">
  Nombre:<span class="required">*</span><input id="acc_f_nombre_0" value="" type="text" class="acc-text upp">
  </label>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.menu-alias {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}
.menu-alias .alias.aliselected {
  background-color: rgba(255,100,0,0.3);
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.menu-alias .alias{
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,100,0,0.1);
}
.menu-alias .alias.ali-nuevo{
  border-right:1px solid;
}
.menu-alias .alias a{
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.facturacion{
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255,100,0,0.3);
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  float:left;
}
```

Here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DytDA/31/) to better understanding. I have not put the jquery code so clicking not works but it is undertandable what it has to do in my opinion.

If you change the 0.3 transparency on aliselected to 1 you will see that it puts itself over the border, which is what I would like but maintaining the transparency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always put the "transparent" color as `.menu-alias .alias.aliselected` background-color.

```
.menu-alias .alias.aliselected {
   background-color:#f7caad;
   margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/w0mp3r/Lpcrd6jx/1/

Comment: Wow, looks really simple. How can i get the hexadecimal rgb color when needed?

Comment: I mean, if I want a rgba(255,100,0,0.6) transparent this time, how can I get the hexadecimal one?

Comment: @danibg You may use a colorpicker from your browser, colorzilla in FF gives me this : #FFA266

Comment: Yup, just installed colorzilla for google chrome. Works pretty cool. Thank you!

Comment: I usually use some external tool like this one: http://yolijn.com/convert-rgba-to-rgb

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this answers is the opposite of what the OP looked for (my fault), but i leave it here since it brought some infos on how to paint background (`background-clip`).

---

You may fake this border with an inset shadow : http://jsfiddle.net/DytDA/32/

```
.menu-alias .alias.aliselected {
  background-color: rgba(255,100,0,1);
  box-shadow:inset 0 -1px black;/* unblured inset shadow showing at bottom */
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

---

Or you may use background-clip to see it through with   padding over the area to be translucide : http://jsfiddle.net/DytDA/33/

```
.menu-alias .alias.aliselected {
  background-color: rgba(255, 100, 0, 1);
  padding-bottom: 1px;/* size of border underneath to see */
  background-clip: content-box;/* only paint the inside where content 
  stands except padding and borders area */
  margin-bottom: -1px;
 }
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Comment: I have tried both but none of them work at all, you may not understand what my intention was, or I do not apply your changes properly. The other answer does the trick.

Comment: @danibg I guess i understood the opposite, you wanted to hide it, didn't you ;)

Comment: Yes, I did not want to show the border when the class was  `.aliselected` thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: @danibg You are welcome,Still I  hope i did bring you some interessting infos.

Comment: Of course you did. I did not know about background-clip. May use it in the future :D